# Performing a sub-group comparison using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame of persons with various person attributes. My structure looks similar to below where each person is identified by PersonID but could have multiple entries except 1000s or records and has a few more attributes. I am trying to flag within group discrepancies across entries. For Example, 25694 has discrepant Sex, 45899 has different Race codes, 69897 has non-matching DOB, etc.

I am trying to flag personIDs with within group discrepancies and output these to a separate data frame.

```
PersonID     Sex      DOB           Race
10123          M      10/12/1986       A
10123          M      10/12/1986       A
25694          M      08/21/1957       W
25694          F      08/21/1957       W
45899          F      04/12/1975       W
45899          F      04/12/1975       U
10229          M      05/17/1989       W
10229          M      05/17/1989       W
10229          M      05/17/1989       W
69897          F      09/10/1995       U
69897          F      09/10/1995       U
69897          F      09/20/1995       A
55554          M      04/02/1988       B
55554          M      04/02/1988       B
```

Output:

```
25694          M      08/21/1957       W
25694          F      08/21/1957       W
45899          F      04/12/1975       W
45899          F      04/12/1975       U
69897          F      09/10/1995       U
69897          F      09/10/1995       U
69897          F      09/20/1995       A
```

I can group the data by personID using

```
library(dplyr)

test <- myData %>% 
   add_count(PersonId) %>% 
   filter(n > 1) %>% 
   select(PersonId, Sex, DOB, Race)
```

But the within group evaluation is tricky.

Any help with this is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `n_distinct` with `filter` to find groups that have more than one entry.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  filter(n_distinct(Sex, DOB, Race) > 1, .by = PersonID)

  PersonID Sex        DOB Race
1    25694   M 08/21/1957    W
2    25694   F 08/21/1957    W
3    45899   F 04/12/1975    W
4    45899   F 04/12/1975    U
5    69897   F 09/10/1995    U
6    69897   F 09/10/1995    U
7    69897   F 09/20/1995    A
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant or efficient. Get the discrepant ids, and then filter by those ids.

```
discrepant <- myData |>
  summarise(across(everything(), ~length(unique(.))), .by = PersonID) |>
  filter(Sex > 1 | DOB > 1 | Race > 1) |>
  pull(PersonID)

myData |> filter(PersonID %in% discrepant)
  PersonID Sex        DOB Race
1    25694   M 08/21/1957    W
2    25694   F 08/21/1957    W
3    45899   F 04/12/1975    W
4    45899   F 04/12/1975    U
5    69897   F 09/10/1995    U
6    69897   F 09/10/1995    U
7    69897   F 09/20/1995    A
```